# Sequence diagram for only one class

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

I have one java class which has all the logic in it. It has 10 methods. Everything happens in this class. How can I modell it? Or how can I show its functionality? I have tried a sequence diagramm but it only has calls to itself.

What is the best solution to modell it? Or to explain how the class works?

Comment: User1006115: The design part is decided depends upon the project needs. So you have to design in a way, It should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where you have complex , internal logic to a component, we often use Activity Diagrams.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/2802.html

Sequence diagrams, as you have suggested, are used for describing complex, multiple component, sequential operations, where component dependencies and the order of calls is critical for understanding.

However, when we want to describe the decision making from a logical perspective, which is much more often the case when dealing with a single class, Activity Diagrams are an appropriate choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a method and just reverse it into a sequence diagram.